# What risks are associated with SPO/Onedrive/O365 external user accounts in active directory?

Tags: active-directory, risk-management, risk-analysis, risk, business-risk

We've recently started using O365/SPO/OneDrive for business as a sharing platform over a previous niche provider platform. I've noticed that each time a user shares content externally, the external user gets an account in our AD. It's unprivileged and unlicensed, but it's still a user credential that's now in our Active Directory.

What risks do you see associated with these user accounts?

What routine mitigations should we be putting in place?

Thanks!